# Jquery .load doing first load, but not second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, razor

Im trying to make a call to another page, to recieve the code on that page. When I do this the first time calling `JSON.cshtml` it works fine, but when calling `JSON2.cshtml` it returns nothing. How can this be?

Default.cshtml

```
@{  
Layout = "~/_Layout_Main.cshtml";
}

@section head{
<script>
    $(".btn").click(function ()
    {
        get_update();
    });

    function get_update()
    {
        $("#success").load("JSON2.cshtml");
    };

    function get_contact()
    {
        $("#success").load("JSON.cshtml");
    };
</script>
}

<div id="success"></div>

<script>
get_contact();
</script>

<a href="#" class="btn" style="color: #fff;">btn</a>
```

JSON.cshtml

```
<p style="color: #fff;">
Hello
</p>
```

JSON2.cshtml

```
@{
for(int i = 0; i > 10; i++)
{
    <p style="color: #fff;">
        @i
    </p>
    <br />
}
}
```

Comment: Because you are downloading a view directly and not executing an Action in the context of the ASP.NET MVC Framework. You will need to create an Action to return this JSON2.cshtml view, then the execution of the code will occur.

Comment: @Moby'sStuntDouble Can you show me an example of how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple really. You will need to create a Controller:

```
public class YourController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult JSON2()
    {
        return View()
    }
}
```

Then in your view/jquery:

```
$("#success").load('@Url.Action("JSON2", "YourController")');
```

Make sure that the name of your controller matches the name of the folder where your JSON2.cshtml view sits, ergo the View will be found by the framework.

I would humbly suggest that you have a look through the Getting Started Tutorials here: http://www.asp.net/mvc